# Progressdialog freeze when multiple marker showing on map in android

Tags: android, progressdialog, google-maps-android-api-2

I am showing multiple markers in google maps API V2 android. below my code in which progressdialog hangs and listmodelUserTrackings has 448 data for display on map.please help me to solve this problem. advance in thanks

```
int i=0;
public void showMarker() {
    showProgressDialog();
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                if (i < listmodelUserTrackings.size()) {
                    int pos = i;
                    Log.v("log_tag", "thread  sleep");
                    final double lat = Double
                            .parseDouble(listmodelUserTrackings.get(pos)
                                    .getLAT());
                    final double lng = Double
                            .parseDouble(listmodelUserTrackings.get(pos)
                                    .getLONG());
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putDouble("lat", lat);
                    bundle.putDouble("longi", lng);

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            String city = null;
                            try {
                                city = getAddress(lat,lng).get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                            }
                            if (city != null) {
                                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                                        lat,lng));

                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                                        new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(
                                        city));
                                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                } else {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: why don't you use asynctask isntead?

Comment: have u get all the markers in map? and progress dialog is dismissing ever?

Comment: yes i have get all markers in map and after that progress dialog dissmiss but progress dialog  is hang

Comment: use asyncTask instead of handler and dismiss dialog in onPostExecute ... that may work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that you do network operation on main thread.

Move this code:

```
String city = null;
try {
    city = getAddress(lat,lng).get(0).getAddressLine(1);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
}
```

into background thread.

Comment: yes thanks it is main thing which affect on progressdialog. thanks a lot